# Why isn't my vector equation solving correctly

Tags: equation-solving, vector

Completely new to Mathematica, started using it yesterday. Don't have the luxury of time to read through a whole long 300 pages manual.

I need to calculate a point on two lines such that the vector between these points its perpendicular to both lines.

Define my points

```
A = {2, 1, -1};
B = {24, -2, 3};
qa = {23, 21, 3};
qb = {-12, -14, 2};
```

Solve for `t1`, and `t2`, the parameters for which the constraints are satisfied

```
sol = Solve[{
    Dot[(A*t1 + qa) - (B*t2 + qb), A] == 0,
    Dot[(A*t1 + qa) - (B*t2 + qb), B] == 0
    }, {t1, t2}];
```

Extracting solutions and obtaining the points to which they refer, from the parameters

```
res = {a, b} /. sol[[1]];
r1 = res[[1]]
r2 = res[[2]]
p1 = A*r1 + qa;
p2 = B*r2 + qb;
```

I my test is `n`, the normal vector

```
n = Cross[A, B]
```

I compute the difference vector from the two points

```
dp = p2 - p1
```

And check if the dot products are zero

```
Dot[n, B](* => 0*)
```

But for `dp` it is not.

```
Dot[dp, B] (*=> not zero, but  *)
```

What is going on?

Comment: In general it is recommended not to use capitol letters for user defined symbols as they may collide with predefined Mathematica symbols.

Answer (score 5):

What you did wrong was to not look at the intermediate results you were getting. If you had that you would have seen

```
res = {a, b} /. sol[[1]]
```

> `{a, b}`

which is, of course, useless.

What you really want is

```
{a, b} = {t1, t2} /. sol[[1]]
```

> `{-(28017/1685), 166/1685}`

Then

```
p1 = A*a + qa;
p2 = B*b + qb;
{p1, p2}
```

> `{{-(17279/1685), 7368/1685, 33072/1685}, 
>   {-(16236/1685), -(23922/1685), 3868/1685}}`

```
dp = p2 - p1
```

> `{1043/1685, -(6258/337), -(29204/1685)}`

```
Dot[dp, B]
```

> `0`